# laplace transform of difference between two gamma independent random variables

Tags: random-variables, laplace-transform, gamma-distribution

Knowing that the laplace transform of a Gamma distribution is given by:

$$F_x(s)  = \frac{\beta^a}{(s + \beta)^a}$$

and that for Z = X + Y "Sum of two independent Gamma distribution random variables"
$$F_z(s)  = (\frac{\beta_x}{s + \beta_x})^a (\frac{\beta_y}{s + \beta_y})^b$$

I am trying to evaluate W= X - Y in the S domain for both X and Y are positive.

1- Is it correct to write:
$$F_w(s)  = (\frac{\beta_x}{s + \beta_x})^a (-1)( \frac{-\beta_y}{s - \beta_y})^b$$

2- If I am interested in the Inverse Laplace (I know it is not easy) how can I get to the two domains namely "$w>0$" and "$w<0$" from one S function. I don't want to get the actual expression of $f_z(z)$ just how is it transformed into two domains.

3- What if $s=\beta_y$ what will be the value or the meaning of  $F_w(s)$

Comment: The answer to 1 is a resounding "no".  See this for details: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48378/difference-of-gamma-random-variables 

The problem is a lot more messy than the sum of two gamma variables.

Comment: I saw the answer in http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/48378 before thinking about the S domain. But the inverse laplace of the simple function I wrote will give the messy answer you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The distribution of $W=X-Y$ for independent $X\sim\operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha_1,\beta_1)$ 
 and $Y\sim\operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha_2,\beta_2)$ is known to be
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:GamDiff_general}
f_W(y) 
=
\begin{cases}
\frac{C_W}{\Gamma(\alpha_2)}\,e^{\beta_2w}\,U(1-\alpha_2,2-\alpha_o,-\beta_ow) ,  &w \leq 0,\\
\frac{C_W}{\Gamma(\alpha_1)}\,e^{-\beta_1w}\,U(1-\alpha_1,2-\alpha_o,\beta_ow),  &w > 0,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\alpha_o=\alpha_1+\alpha_2$, $\beta_o=\beta_1+\beta_2$, 
 and $C_W=\beta_1^{\alpha_1}\beta_2^{\alpha_2}\beta_o^{1-\alpha_o}$. To get the laplace transform of this pdf you can use [DLMF 13.10.7](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.10#E7) with $\nu=1$.  The solution will be the sum of two functions of $s$.